# Google cloud vision API image request

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cloud-vision

I would like to get the data from Google cloud vision API and see the input can be given in the base64 and image uri format.But base64 appears to be too long and to upload the image as uri it take some extra time.Please let me know if anyone knows of any other work around for this.

Comment: Why would Base64 be too long? You could also upload to cloud storage, this way it's already on Google's servers and delay is minimized

Answer (score 0):

I've been downsizing the images by some factor. Reducing by x4 for me has had no impact on the face detections. It might be worth trying.